# Desglose de filas en sql-server

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo puedo crear una consulta en sql server de tal forma que cada fila se desglose según las columnas que no son cero rellenando el resto de filas con cero? Por ejemplo:
Dada la tabla 'mitabla':

```
 col1  col2   col3   col4
  7      2      0       4
  0      3      1       0
  .      .      .       .
  .      .      .       .
```

se transformase en lo siguiente:

```
 col1  col2   col3   col4
  7      0      0       0
  0      2      0       0
  0      0      0       4
  0      3      0       0
  0      0      1       0
  .      .      .       .
  .      .      .       .
```

y así para cada fila

Comment: sql no inventa datos.. por lo menos, no con un query, podrias hacer un proceso para eso.. pero intentaste algo??? porque no suena nada logico (por lo menos, para lo quehace una base de datos)....

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes mostrar lo que intentaste

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes de hacer, es convertir las columnas en filas para poder generar las filas adicionales. Esto se puede hacer utilizando la instrucción APPLY y generando varias filas a partir de los valores de las columnas mediante el constructor de tablas `VALUES` o utilizando `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT  up.*
FROM Prueba
CROSS APPLY( VALUES( col1, 1),
                   ( col2, 2), 
                   ( col3, 3),
                   ( col4, 4) ) up(valor, columna)
WHERE valor <> 0; -- Eliminamos las filas con cero
```

Una vez hecho eso, tenemos que volver a generar las columnas mediante el uso de expresiones `CASE`.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN columna = 1 THEN valor ELSE 0 END AS col1,
        CASE WHEN columna = 2 THEN valor ELSE 0 END AS col2,
        CASE WHEN columna = 3 THEN valor ELSE 0 END AS col3,
        CASE WHEN columna = 4 THEN valor ELSE 0 END AS col4
FROM Prueba
CROSS APPLY( VALUES( col1, 1),
                   ( col2, 2), 
                   ( col3, 3),
                   ( col4, 4) ) up(valor, columna)
WHERE valor <> 0;
```

Normalmente, esto lo vas a ver con funciones de agregado, pero eso es solo cuando quieres agrupar múltiples filas. En este caso, no habrá ninguna agrupación.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción bastante similar, es utilizar un cross join, para generar las filas de más y luego case, para escoger de entre ellas.

```
Declare @table table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
Insert into @table(col1, col2, col3, col4)
values
(7,2,0,4),
(0,3,1,0);

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  
        case numcol when 1 then data.col1 else 0 end as col1,
        case numcol when 2 then data.col2 else 0 end as col2,
        case numcol when 3 then data.col3 else 0 end as col3,
        case numcol when 4 then data.col4 else 0 end as col4
    FROM @table data CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4))T(numCol)
    ) AS SOURCE
WHERE NOT(SOURCE.col1=0 AND SOURCE.col2=0 AND SOURCE.COL3=0 AND SOURCE.COL4=0);
```

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es mediante múltiples consultas y `UNION ALL` para unirlas todas:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (
        SELECT  col1, 0 as Col2, 0 as Col3, 0 as Col4 FROM MiTabla
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  0 as col1, Col2, 0 as Col3, 0 as Col4 FROM MiTabla
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  0 as col1, 0 as Col2, Col3, 0 as Col4 FROM MiTabla
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  0 as col1, 0 as Col2, 0 as Col3, Col4 FROM MiTabla
    ) T
    WHERE   T.Col1 <> 0 
        OR T.Col2 <> 0 
        OR T.Col3 <> 0      
        OR T.Col4 <> 0
```

Comentarios

- Debes definir previamente las columnas que participan en la consulta, no hay nada dinámico en esto.
- Obviamente, tienes un tema de performance, más columnas más consultas
- La otra alternativa ya te la comentaron, un cursor y una "expansión" de filas por cada "celda".

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, me sirven todas. Al final he podido dar con la solución por mi mismo que comparto por si en el futuro a alguien le sirve con la función `UNPIVOT` :

```
Declare @table1 table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
Insert into @table1(col1, col2, col3, col4)
values
(7,2,0,4),
(0,3,1,0);
SELECT  
  col1 = CASE WHEN col = 'col1' THEN value ELSE 0 END,
  col2 = CASE WHEN col = 'col2' THEN value ELSE 0 END,
  col3 = CASE WHEN col = 'col3' THEN value ELSE 0 END,
  col4 = CASE WHEN col = 'col4' THEN value ELSE 0 END


FROM @table1 data
UNPIVOT (
  value FOR col IN (col1,col2,col3,col4)
) AS unpvt
```

posteriormente habría que eliminar las filas que son todo ceros.